# Would a creature be able to see through a Wall of Thorns spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

A lot of arguments tonight in this session, one of them about what a huge crocodile can see from inside of a wall of thorns a druid just cast. Would the huge crocodile see a PC behind the wall or would it, for example, have to roll perception or suffer disadvantage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to RAW, the wall is 20 feet high and 5 feet thick (assuming that it's a circle, since you said "around") and it also says that they wall, "blocks line of sight".  Were I the DM in this case, I would rule that the crocodile can't see through the wall.

Comment: To improve this answer, you could address/acknowledge the creature's size: as per the MM, a *huge* creature occupies a 15x15 ft^2 space, and could potentially be up to 15 ft tall. So, 15 < 20 (plus, its a crocodile, so, close to the ground...)